# 500 internal server error on wp-admin only

Tags: admin, wp-admin, admin-menu

I am getting a 500 internal server error when I try to log into www.mysite.com/wp-admin/ and www.mysite.com/wp-login.php.

- The actual site is up and running just fine so it cannot be a database error.
- I have stripped the plugins from the site through FTP.
- I have re-copied the `.htaccess` file and put in what WordPress recommended.
- I even went in and `define('RELOCATE',true)` as WordPress suggested.

None of these worked. I am not sure what else it could be because the main site is working just not the admin side. Has anyone come across this issue? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled WP_DEBUG?

Comment: It says this: Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use

__construct()

instead. in /home/instant/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3624

Comment: but it looks as if that line is just the error message

Comment: did you check the .htaccess in wp-admin folder. it could be corrupt. disable the plugins that has access to wp dashboard and admin area.

Comment: There is no .htaccess file in the wp-admin directory. Just the root directory. I have disabled all of the plugins and it still didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

500 can be caused due to these ->

Corrupted WP core files
Corrupted .htaccess files
Problematic plugins
PHP memory limit issues
Problematic theme

As you already

- I have re-copied the .htaccess file and put in what WordPress recommended.
- I have stripped the plugins from the site through FTP.

I think
 Upload fresh copy of wp-admin and wp-includes to your WordPress site
Can help.

This article has other solutions too, Please do check
https://www.navthemes.com/http-error-500-wordpress/

Comment: Can you please add all the relevant solutions locally on this site? Thank you.